# Error when trying to join a view in linq-to-sql

Tags: linq-to-sql

While trying to extract data from a view by joining it with two other tables, I'm getting the following error: "SQL Server does not handle comparison of NText, Text, Xml, or Image data types."

And here is the query:

```
    var expeditions = from VE in context.ViewExpeditions
                      join SIAGR in context.SiteInAdviseGoodsRef on VE.DeliveryNotes equals SIAGR.Value
                      join SIA in context.SiteInAdvise on SIAGR.SiteInAdviseId equals SIA.Id
                      where SIA.Id == SiteInAdviseID
                      select VE;
```

Here is the View ViewExpeditions:

```
SELECT ve.*, S.[$Refex] as SiteRefex,c.[$Refex] as ServiceRefex , DeliveryNotes = LEFT(o.list, LEN(o.list)-1),st.Status,st.StatusRefex 
from(
SELECT     
B.[$Id] AS Booking,
B.[$Refex] AS BookingRefex,
B.SiguxCPUE AS CartaDePorte,
SUM(ISNULL(BG.Weight, 0)) AS Weight,
SUM(ISNULL(BG.Volume, 0)) AS Volume,
ISNULL( SUBSTRING(B.Comments, 1, 100),'')  AS Comments, 
'Type' = 
      CASE 
         WHEN PickupSite IS NULL THEN 'Pickup'

         ELSE 'Delivery'
      END,
'Name' = 
      CASE 
         WHEN PickupSite IS NULL THEN PickupName

         ELSE DeliveryName
      END,
      'City' = 
      CASE 
         WHEN PickupSite IS NULL THEN PickupCity

         ELSE DeliveryCity
      END,
'PostalCode' = 
      CASE 
         WHEN PickupSite IS NULL THEN PickupPostalCode

         ELSE DeliveryPostalCode
      END,

'ContactName' = 
      CASE 
         WHEN PickupSite IS NULL THEN ISNULL(B.PickupContactName,'')

         ELSE ISNULL(B.DeliveryContactName,'')
      END,
 'ContactPhone' = 
      CASE 
         WHEN PickupSite IS NULL THEN ISNULL(B.PickupContactPhone,'')

         ELSE ISNULL( B.DeliveryContactPhone,'')
      END,



B.PickupDate AS DataExp,
B.DeliveryDate,
coalesce( B.PickupSite,B.DeliverySite) as 'Site',
b.Service,isnull(B.SiguxState,0) as SiguxState

FROM         dbo.BookingGoods AS BG 
INNER JOIN   dbo.Booking AS B ON BG.BookingId = B.[$Id] 

WHERE     (B.ExecutedBy = 2) AND B.SiguxCPUE is not null AND B.[$IsDeleted]=0
GROUP BY  B.PickupCity,b.PickupContactName,b.PickupContactPhone,b.PickupName,b.PickupPostalCode, B.DeliveryName,B.DeliverySite,  B.DeliveryCity, B.DeliveryPostalCode, B.DeliveryContactName, B.DeliveryContactPhone, B.PickupDate,  B.[$Id], B.SiguxCPUE, B.[$Refex], B.Comments,b.PickupSite,B.Service,B.SiguxState,B.DeliveryDate

) ve 
INNER join [ViewBookingActualStatus] st on st.Booking=ve.Booking
INNER join Service c on ve.Service=c.[$Id]
INNER JOIN dbo.Site AS S ON S.[$Id] = ve.Site   
 outer APPLY 
( 
        SELECT distinct
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), dbo.BookingGoodsRef.Value) + ', ' AS [text()] 
        FROM 
            dbo.BookingGoodsRef 
        WHERE 
            dbo.BookingGoodsRef.BookingId = ve.Booking and BookingGoodsRef.Type=13

        FOR XML PATH('') 
    ) o (list)
```

Where am I going wrong about this?

NOTE: If I try to run the query in linqpad, it doesn't give me any errors at all, and generates the following sql:

```
SELECT [t0].[Booking], [t0].[BookingRefex], [t0].[CartaDePorte], [t0].[Weight], [t0].[Volume], [t0].[Comments], [t0].[Type], [t0].[Name], [t0].[City], [t0].[PostalCode], [t0].[ContactName], [t0].[ContactPhone], [t0].[DataExp], [t0].[DeliveryDate], [t0].[Site], [t0].[Service], [t0].[SiguxState], [t0].[SiteRefex], [t0].[ServiceRefex], [t0].[DeliveryNotes], [t0].[Status], [t0].[StatusRefex]
FROM [ViewExpeditions] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [SiteInAdviseGoodsRef] AS [t1] ON [t0].[DeliveryNotes] = [t1].[Value]
INNER JOIN [SiteInAdvise] AS [t2] ON [t1].[SiteInAdviseId] = [t2].[$Id]
WHERE [t2].[$Id] = @p0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you copy the generated SQL from LinqPad into SSMS and try to run it, do you get the results you expect?

I'd guess that the one of the columns on which you're joining (probably `DeliveryNotes`) is `ntext` or `text`. SQL Server can't join on `text` columns - you have to either cast both columns to `varchar` or use a `substring` on both columns.

Comment: I was stupid enough to forget to do .ToString() on the field DeliveryNotes. After doing so, it ran perfectly well!